# How get data in the exist clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get data from table `rem2` but I am unsuccessful. How am I to do this?

```
SELECT *, rem2.id FROM remuneracao_performance_competencia AS competencia
JOIN remuneracao_performance AS rem1 ON competencia.remuneracao_performance_id = rem1.id
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM remuneracao_performance AS rem2 WHERE
        rem1.id <> rem2.id and rem1.cargo_id = rem2.cargo_id AND rem1.frequencia_campanha = rem2.frequencia_campanha AND rem1.modelo_remuneracao = rem2.modelo_remuneracao AND competencia.remuneracao_performance_id <> rem2.id AND rem2.inicio_vigencia_campanha <= competencia.inicio_vigencia and rem2.inicio_vigencia_campanha > rem1.inicio_vigencia_campanha
        ORDER BY rem2.inicio_vigencia_campanha DESC)
ORDER BY cargo_id ASC
```

The error message is

> Error Code: 1051. Unknown column 'rem2.id' in 'field list

Comment: Please elaborate on your lack of success.  The order by clause in your subquery is unnecessary and might be the culprit.

Comment: Please use the following link as a guide to asking a good question: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Additionally, it is unclear if you're unable to get data, as in an empty result, or if you're getting an error message, as I suspect - concurring with @DanBracuk

Comment: You can't get data from `rem2` since that alias is only in context inside your subquery in your EXISTS condition. You will have to join rem2 in your FROM clause to be able to bring in fields from that table. Since your question is light on details, and heavy on confusing nonsensical code, perhaps you could elaborate with some sample data and your desired results and we can help guide you towards a solution.

Comment: Got it! Thank for your help!

Comment: @DanBracuk
I put the order by in the subquery because I need to get the most recent record.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my query to:

```
select distinct competencia.*, rem2.id from remuneracao_performance_competencia as competencia
join remuneracao_performance as rem1 on competencia.remuneracao_performance_id = rem1.id,
     remuneracao_performance as rem2
where 
rem1.id <> rem2.id and
rem1.cargo_id = rem2.cargo_id and rem1.frequencia_campanha = rem2.frequencia_campanha and
rem1.modelo_remuneracao = rem2.modelo_remuneracao and competencia.remuneracao_performance_id <> rem2.id and
rem2.inicio_vigencia_campanha <= competencia.inicio_vigencia and
rem2.inicio_vigencia_campanha > rem1.inicio_vigencia_campanha
group by competencia.id, rem1.cargo_id
```